# Kivy returning black screen on wi

Tags: python, android, windows, kivy

I have been developing a mobile app in Kivy. However, I deleted something in the .py file (cant remember what) and now I cannot get anything other than a black screen when I run the program. I made the .py and .kv files as simple as possible to reduce points of failures and it still doesnt work.

Here is the .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from time import strftime
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'multisamples', '0')




class Anasayfa(Widget):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file(r"C:\Users\Casper\Desktop\my.kv")
class myApp(App):
    def Build(self):
    
        return (kv)
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    myApp().run()
```

There are some unnecessary stuff on import section, they are from the development of the actual app.

Here is the .kv  file:

```
<Anasayfa>
    GridLayout:
        cols:1      
        Label:
            text:"Coming soon"
            color: 1,1,1,1
```

Thats all, I made both files dead simple and they still dont work. There are no error messages, just a black screen and a mouse cursor. The black screen is in full screen as well, but widgets didnt cover the screen when things did work(think of it like viewing a phone screen on a laptop screen).
Here is the event log:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Casper\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-08-26_13.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Casper\anaconda3\envs\CasperEnv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Casper\anaconda3\envs\CasperEnv\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 - Build 25.20.100.6373'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 - Build 25.20.100.6373'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
```

I would be grateful if someone can tell me what is wrong, because I have no idea what is wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `kv` file does not create a root widget, it only creates a rule. You can change:

```
<Anasayfa>
```

to:

```
Anasayfa:
```

so that it creates a root widget.

Another problem is your `myApp` definition. It should have a `build()` method, not a `Build()` method. Likely just a typo.

Comment: I can not believe it was that easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what about folks who still can't get anything to display on the screen?

GridLayout:
        cols:1
        size: root.width, root.height

```
    GridLayout:
        cols:2

        Label:
            Text: "username"

        TextInput:
            multiline:False

        Label:
            Text: "password"

        TextInput:
            multiline:False

    Button:
        text: "confirm"#then save it and run the code
```